# Combining double null check with Tasks

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, .net-4.0

This is the synchronous version of a code I have (very simplified, but it demonstrates the point):

```
private IDictionary<string, string> m_map;
private readonly object m_lock = new object();

private IDictionary<string, string> ConstructTheMap() { ... }

public string MapString(string key)
{
  if (m_map == null)
  {
    lock (m_lock)
    {
      if (m_map == null)
      {
        m_map = ConstructTheMap();
      }
    }
  }
  return m_map[key];
}
```

Now I would like to rewrite it to work asynchronously. Here is the best I could come up with:

```
private volatile TaskCompletionSource<IDictionary<string, string>> m_mapTaskCompletionSource;
private readonly object m_lock = new object();

private Task<IDictionary<string, string>> ConstructTheMapAsync() { ... }

public Task<string> MapString(string key)
{
  if (m_mapTaskCompletionSource == null)
  {
    lock (m_lock)
    {
      if (m_mapTaskCompletionSource == null)
      {
        m_mapTaskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<IDictionary<string, string>>();
        try
        {
          return ConstructTheMapAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
          {
            if (t.Exception != null)
            {
              m_mapTaskCompletionSource.SetException(t.Exception);
              // fall through, will fail anyway when trying to access the result
            }

            m_mapTaskCompletionSource.SetResult(t.Result);

            return t.Result[key];
          });
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
          m_mapTaskCompletionSource.SetException(exc);
          throw;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return m_mapTaskCompletionSource.Task.ContinueWith(t => t.Result[key]);
}
```

I am limited to .NET 4.0 without any option to install [the extension](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/10/22/using-async-await-without-net-framework-4-5.aspx) allowing the usage of the `async` keyword.

Anyway, I have a feeling it could be written better and more compact without the `async` keyword. Any ideas?

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use `Lazy<T>`? It's cleaner than using explicit double-checked locking to start with.

Comment: Can you show how it would be used in my example?

Comment: @mark [Sure thing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx).

Comment: OK, I've got the idea. The problem is that the caching logic inside the method is an implementation detail. This implementation might change and execute the asynchronous logic every time. Using Lazy<T> will cause me to change the signature of the method to return `string` instead of `Task<string>`. But, of course, I can fake it and return a synchronously completed Task...

Comment: @mark : Then why not have `Lazy<Task<string>> lzy = new Lazy<Task<string>>(async () => await GetMyResourceAsync())` ( which boils down to `Lazy<Task<string>> lzy = new Lazy<Task<string>>(GetMyResourceAsync)` )

Comment: @spender - Do you mind arranging it as a proper reply to my question, so it could be credited? Please, do not use `async` and `await`, because I am unable to use them in my environment.